# JSON contains object with specific key and value

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'd like to use Jackson to check whether a JSON contains an object with specific key and value.

E.g.

```
[
  {
    "name": "test1",
    "value": [
      "test1Value"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test2",
    "value": [
      "test2Value"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "test3",
    "value": [
      true
    ]
  }
]
```

and after:

```
JsonNode json = MAPPER.readTree(jsonString);
```

I'd like to have a function to do `hasObject(json, "name", "test2");`

How can I do that?
I can also use java 8.

Thanks

Comment: You will have to iterate over the top level array and check each object within it.

Comment: You probably need a better JSON framework that gives you that option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I found a way.

It uses [Apache Commons Collections](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4) dependency.

```
boolean found = false;
for (JsonNode field : IteratorUtils.toList(json.elements())) {
    if (field.has("name") && field.get("name").textValue().equals("test2")) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

but I would have preferred a java8-style solution!

Comment: You should specify that your solution is dependant upon Apache Common Collections library